# Create nested dictionary from three separate lists with different length

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I need to create one nested dictionary to describe six (6) students scores for 3 exams:

```
dd = {
    'T': {'Exam 1': 100, 'Exam 2': 90, 'Exam 3': 80},
    'M': {'Exam 1': 88, 'Exam 2': 99, 'Exam 3': 111},
    'F': {'Exam 1': 45, 'Exam 2': 56, 'Exam 3': 67},
    'R': {'Exam 1': 59, 'Exam 2': 61, 'Exam 3': 67},
    'U': {'Exam 1': 73, 'Exam 2': 79, 'Exam 3': 83},
    'F': {'Exam 1': 89, 'Exam 2': 97, 'Exam 3': 101}
}
```

Original input and prep are:

```
import pandas as pd

grades = [
    ['Student', 'Exam 1', 'Exam 2', 'Exam 3'],
    ['T', '100', '90', '80'],
    ['M', '88', '99', '111'],
    ['F', '45', '56', '67'],
    ['R', '59', '61', '67'],
    ['U', '73', '79', '83'],
    ['F', '89', '97', '101']
]

headers = grades.pop(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(grades, columns=headers)

df[['Exam 1','Exam 2','Exam 3']] = df[['Exam 1','Exam 2','Exam 3']].astype(int)
```

I can create the lists for dictionary creation:

```
students = df['Student'].tolist()
assignments = list(df.columns.values)
assignments.remove('Student')
```

Problem:

internal dictionary: keys - assignment (3), values - scores (6)
Outer dictionary: keys - students (6), values - assignments (3)

I do not know how to handle the scores list!! It is 6 per assignment but is it a list of lists (3 x 6)??

I would like to use the zip function:

```
keys = students
values = assignments

result = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

but I do not know how to iterate internal dictionary:

```
keys = assignments. (3 elements)
values = scores (has to be 3 by 6) #-  how to iterate it if it is possible at all?

result = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pandas [to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) function directly on your dataframe. However, your dataframe has duplicate students, so you won't be able to get your example dictionary exactly (must have unique keys).

Removing the duplicate "F" student for illustration...

```
import pandas as pd

grades = [

    ['Student', 'Exam 1', 'Exam 2', 'Exam 3'],
    ['T', '100', '90', '80'],
    ['M', '88', '99', '111'],
    ['F', '45', '56', '67'],
    ['R', '59', '61', '67'],
    ['U', '73', '79', '83']
]

headers = grades.pop(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(grades, columns=headers)

df[['Exam 1','Exam 2','Exam 3']] = df[['Exam 1','Exam 2','Exam 3']].astype(int)

df = df.set_index('Student')
dd = df.to_dict(orient='index')
```

```
print(dd)

{'T': {'Exam 1': 100, 'Exam 2': 90, 'Exam 3': 80}, 
'M': {'Exam 1': 88, 'Exam 2': 99, 'Exam 3': 111}, 
'F': {'Exam 1': 45, 'Exam 2': 56, 'Exam 3': 67}, 
'R': {'Exam 1': 59, 'Exam 2': 61, 'Exam 3': 67}, 
'U': {'Exam 1': 73, 'Exam 2': 79, 'Exam 3': 83}}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have two students named "F" but `dict` keys have to be unique. You could then try the following:

```
grades = [
    ['Student', 'Exam 1', 'Exam 2', 'Exam 3'],
    ['T', '100', '90', '80'],
    ['M', '88', '99', '111'],
    ['F', '45', '56', '67'],
    ['R', '59', '61', '67'],
    ['U', '73', '79', '83'],
    ['F', '89', '97', '101']
]

dd = {}
for name, exam1, exam2, exam3 in grades[1:]:
    dd[name] = {'Exam 1': exam1, 'Exam 2': exam2, 'Exam 3': exam3}
```

or:

```
keys = [keys[0] for keys in grades[1:]]
values = [dict(zip(['Exam 1', 'Exam 2', 'Exam 3'], keys[1:])) for keys in grades[1:]]
dd = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

Comment: Both solutions work perfectly. Both are elegant. So I have a hard time selecting a better answer. I gave points to both of you. many thanks! Steven's answer is a bit cuter IMHO. I have never used the orient parameter! great learning!

Comment: @Toly Thanks, I'm glad I could help. And Steven's answer is much better, good you went with it!